# Is using linux HPC good idea for handling large pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, hpc

I am dealing with large pandas dataframe (20-100 millions of rows with around 100 columns). It is too big to handle on PC with 64GB of RAM memory. Is it good idea to run python script on HPC (High Performance Computing) linux cluster? In example if single node has 128GB of RAM, then will Python script fully run if I define PBS job that allocates 2 nodes, with total of 256GB of RAM?

Comment: Your question is too broad but [Dask](https://dask.org) was built for distributing analytics over a large cluster

Comment: It also depends on what exactly you want to do. Maybe there is a way to process it in junks, but Dask is a good advice I guess.